# How to get the duration of a threshold breach in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, data-visualization

I'm looking for a suggested approach to the following that is time efficient in Pandas. Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
[TimeStamp]             [Val] 
2017-08-19 22:28:42.000  151 
2017-08-19 22:28:42.001  127 
2017-08-19 22:29:42.000  149 
2017-08-19 22:34:10.000  127 
2017-08-19 22:35:10.000  126 
2017-08-19 22:36:10.000  132 
2017-08-19 22:37:10.000  129 
2017-08-19 22:39:10.000  124
```

How would I get the duration when the Val exceeds 127?

So I'd expect an answer of:

```
22:28:42 -> 22:28:42.001
22:29:42 -> 22:34:10.000
22:36:10 -> 22:39:10.000
```

I would also like to then look at these date ranges and carry out actions like:
     How many datapoint are there between dates where value is above 127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort your data by TimeStamp

```
>> df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
>> df = df.sort_values('TimeStamp')
```

Then find positions where Val changes to lte or gt 127

```
>> df['changed'] = (df['Val'] > 127).astype(int).diff().fillna(1).astype(int)
>> df
    TimeStamp                   Val     changed
0   2017-08-19 22:28:42.000     151     1
1   2017-08-19 22:28:42.001     127     -1
2   2017-08-19 22:29:42.000     149     1
3   2017-08-19 22:34:10.000     127     -1
4   2017-08-19 22:35:10.000     126     0
5   2017-08-19 22:36:10.000     132     1
6   2017-08-19 22:37:10.000     129     0
7   2017-08-19 22:39:10.000     124     -1
```

Above, for particular TimeStamp

- -1 means that Val changed to lte 127
- +1 means that Val changed to gt 127

Finally construct the time intervals you need

```
>> pd.DataFrame({
>>     't_0': df.loc[df.changed ==  1, 'TimeStamp'].reset_index(drop=True), 
>>     't_n': df.loc[df.changed == -1, 'TimeStamp'].reset_index(drop=True)})

    t_n                         t_0
0   2017-08-19 22:28:42.001     2017-08-19 22:28:42
1   2017-08-19 22:34:10.000     2017-08-19 22:29:42
2   2017-08-19 22:39:10.000     2017-08-19 22:36:10
```

Comment: Constructing the new dataframe causes an error for me: new_fr = pd.DataFrame({'t_0': fr.loc[fr['changed'] == 1, 'Time'].values, 't_n': fr.loc[fr['changed'] == -1, 'Time'].values}) gives: ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: @user7186882 Just pass Series instead of arrays into result df, updated an answer.